# Unable to read repository at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andau/abapCI/master/com.abapci.updateSite/site.xml/content.xml

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, abap

I try to install [ABAP CI Plugin](https://github.com/andau/abapCI) ([Marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/abap-continuous-integration)) in Eclipse but get following error message:

> Unable to read repository at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andau/abapCI/master/com.abapci.updateSite/site.xml/content.xml.
>
> PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

[image: Problem Occurred]

Someone has any clue on how to resolve this issue?

When I try to visit the website (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andau/abapCI/master/com.abapci.updateSite/site.xml/content.xml) there is a 404 not found error.

For reference I use Eclipse 2022-06 and have a SAP S/4HANA 104 System.
Eclipse is installed with the latest ABAP Development Tools and was installed as a Java installation.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I get following error message: `Unable to read repository at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andau/abapCI/master/com.abapci.updateSite/content.xml.
Unable to read repository at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andau/abapCI/master/com.abapci.updateSite/content.xml.
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

Comment: Forget what I said. It works for me with and without `site.xml`. It seem the Java you use to run Eclipse is missing a root certificate to access GitHub via HTTPS. Do you get the same error for [AnyEdit Tools](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/anyedit-tools)? As workaround, downloading the [update site](https://github.com/andau/abapCI/tree/master/repository) and use it via _Help > Install New Software..._ should work.

Comment: Thanks @howlger ! same issue for AnyEdit Tools. I now have pulled the repo from GitHub and added it as you said via Help > Install New Software... 
I guess I have to update Java on my computer / update the certificates there if I want to get them via marketplace...

Comment: You may consider using the eclipse installer to automatically get a modern JDK for eclipse to run on

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen The Eclipse Installer provides the option to include the latest LTS Java version whereas in the ZIP/DMG package it's included. An embedded Java can also be installed into an existing installation: https://download.eclipse.org/justj/www/?page=download